# StackOverFlowError when trying to train neural network with Neuroph framework

Tags: java, neural-network, stack-overflow

I am trying to train a neural network using Neuroph library but I get this error:

```
44 [NeurophLearningThread] INFO org.neuroph.core.learning.LearningRule - Learning Started
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.neuroph.util.NeurophArrayList.writeObject(NeurophArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The thing is, I used the same code to train a neural network in another project which has the same imported jars and it worked properly. Here is the code I used to create and train the NN:

```
public void TrainNeuralNetwork(double[] inputs, double[] outputs){


    DataSet set = new DataSet(inputs.length,outputs.length);
    set.addRow(inputs,outputs);

    System.out.println("Training...");
    MultiLayerPerceptron loadSnakeNN = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.LINEAR, inputs.length, 500, outputs.length);

    if( loadSnakeNN.getLearningRule() instanceof MomentumBackpropagation )
        ((MomentumBackpropagation)loadSnakeNN.getLearningRule()).setBatchMode(true);


    MomentumBackpropagation learningRule = (MomentumBackpropagation)loadSnakeNN.getLearningRule();// Set learningRule

    learningRule.setMaxError(0.01);
    loadSnakeNN.learn(set);
    loadSnakeNN.save("SnakeNN.nnet");
    System.out.println("Neural Network Trained!");
}
```

****Update****

I found where the problem is. When I use more than 90 inputs I get the above error. So my new question is, how to train this neural network with more than 90 inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the stack size available to your program by using JVM parameter `-Xss`.

```
`java -Xss2048m ...`
```

means that you get a stack of `2048Mb`. If you're running this from your IDE you can search to find out how to pass JVM parameters for your specific IDE.

I'm assuming that there is no bug either in your code or the library, otherwise increasing the stack will probably not be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After adding java -Xss2048m, I am trying to run the application but I get this error: Error: Could not find or load main class java. Any hint?

Comment: I found the problem. I had to enter -Xss2048m not java -Xss2048m